# Choosing Between Training on Historical Data vs. Imputed Data for Time Series Nowcasting

Tags: regression, linear-model, data-imputation

I have several time series datasets which we can label as `y`, `x1`, `x2`, ..., `x5`. Particularly interesting is the relationship between `x1` and a newer dataset `z1`. `z1` is akin to an enhanced version of `x1` - it possesses richer information and is on a broader scale due to the encompassed details. However, `z1` has a limited historical record. While `x1` is static with a rich history, `z1` is updated weekly.

**Approach 1: Train on `x1` and use a fitted version of it for new predictions.**

1. Train a model: `y ~ x1 + x2 + ...`
2. Fit `x1` on `z1`: Understand the relationship between them.
3. For future data: Use the mapped value of `z1` (termed "fitted x1") and others for predictions.

**Approach 2: Impute `z1` historically using `x1` and then model on this.**

1. Impute historical `z1` using `x1`.
2. Train a model with both imputed and current `z1` values: `y ~ z1 + x2 + ...`
3. For future data: Use the latest values of `z1` and the rest for predictions.

**Question:**

- Which approach is statistically more sound given the nature of `x1` and `z1`?
- Are there pitfalls in either method that I should be particularly cautious about?
- If both methods have their merits, what factors should guide my choice?

Any insights, references, or experiences shared would be invaluable. Thank you in advance!